NSScrollView's scroller not autohiding on Sequoia
The NSScrollView's scroller remains visible on macOS Sequoia despite the autohidesScrollers being true. On macOS Sonoma and lower the scroller is displayed as a subview of NSScrollView and correctly autohides after some time. It's displayed above the content. On macOS Sequoia this has changed and the scroller is taking space from the displayed content. This can be seen when I use NSStackView (it will resize the content when the scroller becomes hidden/visible). The scroller will hide only if I resize the window/scrollview.
How to autohide scroller on macOS Sequoia? Or is there any workaround to force hide it?

Simple code demonstrating the issue:
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scrollView = NSScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.borderType = .bezelBorder
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true
        scrollView.autohidesScrollers = true
        scrollView.drawsBackground = false
        
        // Create the content view
        let contentView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
        contentView.wantsLayer = true
        contentView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        
        // Set the content view to the scroll view
        scrollView.documentView = contentView
        
        // Add the scroll view to the main view
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // Set Auto Layout constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
    }
}


What are the Show scroll bars settings in System Settings (Appearance)?

@Willeke Many thanks. This is the correct answer.

The System Settings/Preferences affects the showing of scrollbars. Check the "Show scroll bars" in the Appearance panel of System Settings.

